# Swipe only detected on stage, Adobe AIR for iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, jquery-animate, adobe

I'm making an iOS app in Adobe Animate/AIR.  I have a colour palette menu that the user can swipe to pull up.  The weird thing is, it always works when the Listener is added to the stage (not practical).  But when I add it to the menu, it's hit and miss.  It won't register the swipe, but then for some reason it started working perfectly for a while, then stopped again.  It's driving me crazy.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.Regular;

// SWIPE SHELF UP OR DOWN
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
skinColourShelf.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , skinColourShelfOnSwipe); 
function skinColourShelfOnSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    trace("swipe");
    if (e.offsetY == 1 && skinColourShelf.y < 518.7) { 
        //swiped down
        new Tween(skinColourShelf, "y", Regular.easeOut, skinColourShelf.y, 518.7, 1, true);
    } else if (e.offsetY == -1 && skinColourShelf.y > 380) {
        //swiped up
        new Tween(skinColourShelf, "y", Regular.easeOut, skinColourShelf.y, 380, 1, true);
    }
}
```

There's also a button listener on the arrow inside the menu, in case the person prefers to click instead.  At one point it seemed like moving this code after the swipe code did the trick.  But then it stopped working again.  Commenting out the whole bottom section doesn't solve it either, so it's probably not relevant:

```
// CLICK ON ARROW
skinColourShelf.arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, skinColourShelfEase);
function skinColourShelfEase(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (skinColourShelf.y > 380) {
        new Tween(skinColourShelf, "y", Regular.easeOut, skinColourShelf.y, 380, 1, true);
    } else {
        new Tween(skinColourShelf, "y", Regular.easeOut, skinColourShelf.y, 518.7, 1, true);
    }
}
```

At one point adding a large rectangle inside the menu made it work for some reason.  And then it worked even after deleting the shape.  But now it doesn't work again.  What would stop a swipe on an object from registering?  Obviously a shape on top, but clicking on the arrow works.  Is it a conflict between the swipe and button functions inside the menu?  What else can I try?

Oh, I'm only testing using Animate's own simulator, using the "touch and gesture" layer and the swipe setting.  I haven't jumped through the provisioning file hoops yet so I don't know of any other way to easily test.

Comment: So now only one instance of swiping works, at a later frame in the menu.  The listener was added to the object, but seems to work if the screen is swiped literally anywhere; not just on the item the listener was placed on.  So maybe I'm misunderstanding how gesture listeners work?  Is it very different from click event listeners from before?

Comment: Per your description, my guess is you try to make swipe to work where the menu have no substance (no fills, text fields, raster images or other content). Simply, if the initial touch goes anywhere but that menu or its display list children, the whole gesture is missed by menu. Your options are: a) some transparent shape fill to make more area for user to touch or b) **stage**, yes, there's nothing impractical about it.

Comment: Thanks.  There is content but maybe it's not large enough? It's about 1/10 of the height of a mobile screen.  I've been wondering if maybe it stops working when the "mouse out" of the swipe is no longer over the object.  But then again, I had it working earlier and it seemed fine, which is why it's driving me crazy.  Can the program listen for multiple gestures on multiple items at the same time or maybe it cancels the old ones as I try to add new ones..

Comment: Maybe I can work with the stage-swipe mindset.  The left-right can swipe the items in the menu, and the up/down swipe could toggle the colour palette to come up from below. Hm.